# how to re-write clean url and remove space between words

Tags: php, .htaccess

my currrent url is :

```
http://codagu.com/Environmental impact
```

i'm trying to write like :

```
http://codagu.com/Environmental_impact
```

my link look like:

```
<li><a href="http://codagu.com/" ><span>'.str_replace("-"," ",$row['title']).'</span></a>
```

my htaccess code is like what should i change in that to make my url work and replace space with underscore

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^\.html$ / [L]
```

Comment: What's the difference between those two URL's?

Comment: http://codagu.com/Environmental impact in first url  there is gap between enavironmental and impact but i want to replace gap with underscore

Comment: Please update your question to match what you just said. In the question, those two URL's are identical (both have underscores).

Comment: hi @Magnus i updated the question please have a look.

Comment: You already replace `-` with space in the title, where are you stuck? [Documentation for str_replace()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

Comment: yes but it's not working in my case please go through codagu.com/economic impact check this url

Comment: hllo #kerbholz thanks for your concern but when i'm rewriting htaccess file it's giving me found 404 error